# Modelling time-dependent rate using Bayesian statistics (pymc3)

Tags: time-series, bayesian, pymc

**How to model time-dependent variables explicitly? (or alternatively, a better approach to modelling)**

I measure events over time and there are two sources: a) constant rate baseline and b) a time-dependent burst as seen below
[image: Experimental Data]

I want to quantify the difference between these two sources of events and fit the likely parameters from the experimental data.

My modelling assumptions are:

1. Baseline comes from Poisson distribution with fixed mean $\lambda_{a}$
2. Burst comes from Poisson distribution with varying mean $\lambda_{b} (t)$
3. $\lambda_{b} (t)$ is described by a skewed normal distribution with parameters, mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$, skewness $\alpha$, magnitude $mag$

Generating artificial data as a test input. 
$\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$ look like this
[image: lambdas]
and leads to artificial datasets like this
[image: artificial data]

What I struggle with is including the explicit time dependence. In pymc3

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats
    import pymc3 as pm

    #Generate a training set 
    #leads per second
    lambda_a_true = 10

    def skew(x,e=0,w=1,a=0, mag=1):
        t = (x-e) / w
        return 2 * mag * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(t) * scipy.stats.norm.cdf(a*t)

    time = np.linspace(0.0, 300.0, 1000)
    a_t =10 ; mu_t = 35; sigma_t = 25; mag_t = 35
    lambda_b_true = skew(time, mu_t, sigma_t, a_t, mag_t)

    ts=np.arange(301); count=np.zeros(301, dtype = np.uint16)
    for ii in ts:
        bl = np.random.poisson(lam=lambda_a_true)
        tv = np.random.poisson(lam=skew(ii, mu_t, sigma_t, a_t, mag_t))
        count[ii]=bl+tv

    niter = 2000
    with pm.Model() as model:
        #Baseline lambda - one of our unknown
        lambda_bl = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 20)

        #Parameters for skewed Gaussians - also unknowns
        alpha = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 20)
        mu = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 300)
        sigma = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 300)
        mag = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 100)

        #How to include time dependence here?
        lambda_tv = skew(t, mu=mu, sd=sigma, tau=None, alpha=alpha, mag=mag)
```

Comment: Did you look at the "disasters" example in PyMC3 example? I would start by trying to model a mixture: constant vs Poisson components.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs The problem is that it only considers two time periods. If I wanted to use that approach I would have to insert 300 switch statements. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Should I ask this question on StackOverFlow as it is more about the programming part than the statistics part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have more luck with PyMC3 questions on our forums: http://discourse.pymc.io

It sounds like you have a mixture model here where you want to infer which samples come from which distribution. There quite a few examples which you can look at: http://docs.pymc.io/examples.html#mixture-models

While your model should look a bit different afterwards, it's also important to know that using python code in the model creation does not do what you think it does: lambda_tv = skew(t, mu=mu, sd=sigma, tau=None, alpha=alpha, mag=mag). See http://docs.pymc.io/theano.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As @twiecki suggested, the devs at [pymc3](http://discourse.pymc.io/) provided me with an [answer](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/how-to-model-time-dependent-variables-in-pymc3/516/6).

The key to the solution is that theano provides an error function, allowing the skewed distribution to be coded.

> You can wrap the scipy function in theano using @theano.as_op (you can
>   do a search in discourse, there are a few examples). However, you
>   cannot use the gradient doing so it is discouraged.
>
> I would suggest you to rewrite the skew normal shape function in
>   theano, the error function is available in theano, [...]

```
import theano.tensor as tt
def skewnorm_pdf(x, e=0, w=1, a=0, mag=1):
    t = (x-e) / w
    cdf = .5*(1+tt.erf(a*t/np.sqrt(2)))
    pdf = 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*tt.exp(-t**2/2)
    return 2 * mag * pdf * cdf
```

and hence

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    #Baseline lambda - one of our unknown
    lambda_bl = pm.Uniform('lambda_bl', 0., 20)

    #Parameters for skewed Gaussians - also unknowns
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', 0., 300, shape=N_SPOTS)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', 0., 50, shape=N_SPOTS)
    mag = pm.Uniform('mag', 0., 100, shape=N_SPOTS)
    alpha = pm.Uniform('alpha', 0., 50, shape=N_SPOTS)

    lam = lambda_bl + tt.sum( skew_theano(ts,e=mu,w=sigma,a=alpha, mag=mag) )
    cs = pm.Poisson(mu=lam, name='cs', observed=count)
```